# Pinch To Zoom in UIWebView in iphone App

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, zooming

I am Developing simple App. I am accessing **html** pages on `UIWebVIew`. and I wanted to zoom that **html** pages with the help of `zoom` option

please help me out.

Comment: are you loading page from url? or your html code in uiwebview

Answer (score 10):

Zooming **IN, OUT and Pinch** are Built In feature of **UIWebView**. You don't need to write any code to achieve that.
Simply , Use your fingers.

On Simulator , you can use **Option (Alt)** and **Shift** Keys with **Mouse**.

Make your option **Scale Page to Fit ON**.

Comment: @jitendra: Use option (alt) key to test on Simulator

Comment: @jitendra: If my Answer solved your Question then Mark it as Accepted, So that It can help Future Visitors.

Answer (score 5):

Try this below property

webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

Answer (score 2):

First of all set this property given below:

```
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

Then you have to set view port on meta data on the html string. In my case head tag was empty. Thats why I just replaced head with the with head containing meta tag.

```
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<head></head>"
                                                 withString:@"<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=568\"/></head>"];
    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Storyboard :**

There is built-in property of WebView `‘Scales Page To Fit’` which is false by default.

`Select WebView` -> `Open Utilities Window` -> `Goto Attribute Inspector’`

Set `‘Scales Page To Fit’` to true (Checkmark it)

[image: Screenhshot1]

**Programmatically :**

```
objWebView.scalesPageToFit = true
```